# link trigger on page load is not working

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, triggers, click, document-ready

I'm making a simple example on triggering a click on a link on page load but it's not working. I don't want to navigate the that href I just want the trigger to work for something else I'll work on
here's the head code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $("a#test").trigger('click');
},1000);
});

</script>
```

and the body code

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" id="test">click</a>
```

Comment: Try using $('#test').click()

Comment: but .click() requires me to clock the link I want the link to get clicked automatically

Comment: When you add a callback in click at that time It is required to be clicked by you else it will act as a short hand of trigger http://jsfiddle.net/7pnLS/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        $( "#test" ).on( "click", function() {
             alert('Clicked');
             window.location.href = $( this ).attr('href'); //automatic redirection from the link href
             console.log('clicked');
            });

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#test").trigger('click');
        },1000);
    });
```

Comment: it alerts but link not working the code before editing worked can you post it again ?

Comment: I was dumped that line, added that line now please check it out

Comment: but why the link doesn't get clicked without using the .on function?

Comment: Actually, your code was triggered, but not added the click handler function. now added into that.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually working but it doesn't redirect you.

You can see an example here.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("a#test").trigger('click');
},1000);
$("a").on('click', function(){
    $(this).css('font-size', 50)
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7pnLS/)